# Localizar em um array o próximo valor maior do que um valor pré definido

Tags: php, array, value

Tenho o seguinte array com forech definido:

```
$getdepth = '{"result":"true","asks":[[20,13],[34,20],[30,8],[35,8],[4,40],"bids":[["18",22],["16",74],["70",99],["65",18],["1",15]]}';
$depth = json_decode($getdepth, true);
foreach ($depth['asks'] as $k_asks => $v_asks) {
$array_asks[$k_asks] = $v_asks[0];}
```

Queria saber como fazer uma função para descobrir o próximo valor em "asks" maior do que "30". Analisando visualmente, a solução é 34.

Obs.: O teste de valor a valor seria uma solução, mas o array original contém mais de 2000 valores, o que torna a comparação inviável devido a alta carga de processamento.

Comment: Quando você diz "próximo" você quer dizer o primeiro (na ordem) ou o mais baixo (tipo, se o `35` aparecesse antes do `34`, qual dos dois você ia querer)? E essa operação vai ser realizada uma só vez, ou várias?

Comment: Quando digo próximo, me referiro a ordenar todos os valores em ordem crescente e encontrar aquele que é o maior que a definição (30) --> 4, 20, 30, 34, 35. Será realizada várias vezes e o array $getdepth não é fixo altera a cada minuto.

Comment: OK. Escrevi uma resposta. Infelizmente, não vai dar pra fazer com menos que uma passada completa na lista. E se ela muda o tempo todo, a solução mais simples provavelmente terá a melhor performance na prática (a menos que você tenha de fazer centenas ou mais de buscas diferentes na mesma lista, antes que ela mude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dificilmente você vai conseguir uma solução melhor que testar de valor a valor. Uma passada completa na lista é `O(n)`, e isso é o limite ao qual você pode chegar - pois no pior caso (i.e. o valor que você quer não existe ou ele é o último a ser testado) você terá que avaliar todos os elementos da lista pelo menos uma vez. Aliás, se o que você quer for um "minimax" (i.e. o menor valor maior que `30` - e não o primeiro da lista, na ordem, que for maior que `30`) então você vai ter que dar uma passada completa de qualquer jeito (pra garantir que não há um valor menor mais pra frente).

Se isso for uma operação isolada, infelizmente não tenho nada melhor a sugerir... Mas se isso for algo que você precisa fazer repetidas vezes, então dá pra **amortizar** o tempo de busca de uma das duas maneiras abaixo:

1. Ordene o array uma vez (`O(n*log(n))`) e, para cada busca que for fazer, utilize a [pesquisa binária](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesquisa_bin%C3%A1ria#C.C3.B3digo_em_PHP) (`O(log(n))`). Para uma única operação isso será mais lento (`> O(n)`), mas para múltiplas operações será mais rápido (`< O(m*n)`, desde que `m > log(n)` fora o fator constante).
2. Coloque seus elementos em uma [árvore binária de busca](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca) (mesma ordem de complexidade da solução acima).

As soluções acima se aplicam ao caso "minimax". No outro caso, antes de aplicar a solução sugerida crie um array com os valores máximos encontrados até cada índice:

```
[[20,13],      [34,20],      [30,8],      [35,8],      [4,40]     ]
[[20,[20,13]], [34,[34,20]], [34,[30,8]], [35,[35,8]], [35,[4,40]]]
```

E faça essa ordenação/busca nele, em vez do array original.

P.S. Você está tendo problemas de performance na prática? 2000 elementos não me parece algo excessivamente grande pra justificar uma solução mais complexa...

Comment: Complexa a sua resposta. O sistema roda em dois servidores, um que fornece as informações do banco de dados (array) e o terminal (PC) que executará essa rotina além de outras que também serão executadas ao mesmo tempo. Além do lag de conexão servidor/terminal.

Comment: @user3486019 Pois é, minha recomendação é não mexer com isso não. Testa de valor a valor mesmo, pois tem boa chance da performance global ser melhor. Ou, se viável, faz a parte demorada (ordenar a lista ou criar a árvore de busca, o que for mais fácil) no servidor mais rápido, e deixa a busca em si pro mais lento.